# git password prompting in RHEL

Tags: linux, git, rhel, rhel5

I'm on an RHEL machine and it seems that git uses a GUI password prompt when I try to clone private repositories. I'd like it to use the terminal itself. How can I set git to behave in that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using askpass? Then try to do

```
$ unset SSH_ASKPASS
```

to disable it, because the mask is triggered by ssh and not git.